# "Class 'App\Game\User' not found" even with changed providers

Tags: laravel, authentication

When i try to register an account it comes up with this error " class App\Game\user" not found

I have changed the providers auth.php to App\Game\User::class, 
and i have changed the name space on the user.php to namespace App\Game;

Game.php does exist (however nothing is coded in it and im wondering if this is the problem?)

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Game\User::class,
        ],
```

the browser highlights the return line in this part of the RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)    
{
return User::create([    
'name' => $data['name'],    
'email' => $data['email'],    
'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),    
]);    
}
```

Edit: I didn't realize it meant folders in the naming convention and put them into the appropriate folders. Thank you. My apologies i couldn't find a question relating to this on stackover flow and ive only just started on laravel

Comment: do you have `Game` folder in your app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you have something like App\Game\User::Class
That means you will have a game folder inside the app folder and then user.php file in that Game folder with. You can use the full namespace to call the class like \App\Game\User if it's still not working try to run composer dump-autoload to regenerate the composer files.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model stores under app>user.php and make sure your file does exist in app>game folder